# How do I customize the MediaWiki SEARCH form to include help text for users?

Tags: search, mediawiki

We're using MediaWiki 1.21.1, and I've been reading the Sidebar documentation because I want to add some brief help text to the Search form.

I've found that the Wiki admin customizes the Sidebar using the URL:

```
http://wikihost/wiki/index.php5?title=MediaWiki:Sidebar&action=edit
```

and within that page, you add the Search form using the entry:

```
* SEARCH
```

However, I can't seem to find anything that explains how *SEARCH* gets translated into the HTML input form.  I'm thinking if I can find where that happens, I can add some brief help text for our users.

Comment: * SEARCH is a special token that gets parsed by MediaWiki's internals and transformed into a search box. If you want to add extra text, you're probably going to have to create a custom skin to do so. :\

Comment: So there's no template file sitting somewhere on disk for the form?  If not, then creating a custom skin is way beyond the scope of what I want to do here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you "@i alarmed alien" for the mention of custom skins.  Your comment prompted me to do a quick search of the MonoBook skin files just to see what it was doing for the *SEARCH* token before I gave up on this task.

What I found was the file */var/www/wiki/skins/MonoBook.php* which contains the *searchBox()* function to generate the input form.  I was able to add my help text to that routine -- a kludge, I know, and I will have to manually carry forward my change whenever we upgrade MediaWiki, but it works for us.